Google app script not populating the html file with fetched data
Html file:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <form id="searchForm">
    <input type="text" id="searchInput" pattern="[0-9]*" placeholder="Enter a number">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  <div id="output"></div>

  <script>
    // Function to handle form submission
    function handleFormSubmission(event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission
      var searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput').value;
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayData).searchSheet(searchInput); // Call searchSheet function with the input value

    }

    // Function to display data returned from server-side script
    // Function to display data returned from server-side script

    function displayData(rowData) {


      var outputDiv = document.getElementById('rowData');
      outputDiv.innerHTML = ''; // Clear previous content

      if (rowData.length > 0) {
        var table = document.createElement('table');
        table.border = '1';

        for (var i = 0; i < rowData.length; i++) {
          var row = table.insertRow();
          var cell = row.insertCell();
          cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rowData[i]));
        }

        outputDiv.appendChild(table);
      } else {
        outputDiv.innerText = 'No matching data found';
      }
    }

    // Attach event listener to form submission
    document.getElementById('searchForm').addEventListener('submit', handleFormSubmission);
  </script>
</body>

</html>



in code.gs
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index').setTitle('Search Google Sheet');
}

function searchSheet(searchInput) {
  // Get the data from the Google Sheet
  var sheetId = '1kgy9u1N2t6-zklLcn7UUuPhl6I_HRo-go3WeZIspDME';
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId).getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Search for the number in the first column
  var rowFound = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] == searchInput) {
      rowFound = data[i];
      Logger.log("Found matching data in row: " + (i + 1)); // Log the data of the iteration
      break;
    }
  };
  Logger.log("Found matching data in row: " + rowFound); // Log the data of the iteration
  // Create HTML content for output
  var html = '<table border="1">';
  if (rowFound) {

    for (var i = 0; i < rowFound.length; i++) {
      html += '<tr>';
      for (var j = 0; j < rowFound[i].length; j++) {
        html += '<td>' + rowFound[i][j] + '</td>';
      }

      html += '</tr>';
    }
    html += '</table>';
  } else {
    html += '<tr><td>No matching data found</td></tr>';
  }
  html += '</table>';

  var rowData = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  // Log the value of the output variable
  Logger.log("rowdata: " + rowData);
  return rowData;
}

function logData(data) {
  Logger.log("Search input value: " + data);
}

The searchsheet function in code.gs file fetches the data from google sheet but the fetched data is not getting transferred to displaydata function so that after submitting the input, the table gets displayed on the webpage as desired. The displaydata function seem to have some problem in execution.
How should I return the row fetched by searchsheet function as a table to the index.html file so that after searching the input and pressing the submit button populates the html page with data fetched from google sheet.
What am i doing wrong?
